# Tkinter button calling function to play wave with PyAudio -- crashes

Tags: python, button, tkinter, crash, pyaudio

As soon as I hit the button, it stays pressed, and the program crashes. The sound does play though. I'm using code straight form the PyAudio site so I'm a little confused here why it crashes.

```
from tkinter import *
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

root = Tk()
root.title("Compose-O-Matic")
root.geometry("400x300")

def play_audio():
    chunk = 1024
    wf = wave.open('misc_environment3.wav', 'rb')
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(
        format = p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
        channels = wf.getnchannels(),
        rate = wf.getframerate(),
        output = True)

    data = wf.readframes(chunk)

    while data != '':
        stream.write(data)
        data = wf.readframes(chunk)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

button_start = Button(app, text = ">", command = play_audio)
button_start.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: do you get any error message ? maybe problem is that your function work too long and mainloop can't do its job - use `threads`.

Comment: How exactly would I use threading for this? I've tried putting the function in a threaded class, using "class AudioFile(threading.Thread):" or even putting the play audio function inside of threading.Thread() but I'm still getting the same result. I'm thinking maybe the issue is the while loop not breaking but that code is straight out of the PyAudio documentation (doesn't crash when I comment out the while loop, though of course then file doesn't play).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `threading` to play music.

```
from tkinter import *
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys
import threading

# --- classes ---

def play_audio():
    global is_playing
    chunk = 1024
    wf = wave.open('misc_environment3.wav', 'rb')
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(
        format = p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
        channels = wf.getnchannels(),
        rate = wf.getframerate(),
        output = True)

    data = wf.readframes(chunk)

    while data != '' and is_playing: # is_playing to stop playing
        stream.write(data)
        data = wf.readframes(chunk)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()

# --- functions ---

def press_button_play():
    global is_playing
    global my_thread

    if not is_playing:
        is_playing = True
        my_thread = threading.Thread(target=play_audio)
        my_thread.start()

def press_button_stop():
    global is_playing
    global my_thread

    if is_playing:
        is_playing = False
        my_thread.join()

# --- main ---

is_playing = False
my_thread = None

root = Tk()
root.title("Compose-O-Matic")
root.geometry("400x300")

button_start = Button(root, text="PLAY", command=press_button_play)
button_start.grid()

button_stop = Button(root, text="STOP", command=press_button_stop)
button_stop.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I changed code to add STOP button and `is_playing` to stop music inside thread.